# How to redirect to another webpage

Tags: go, redirect, go-gin

**What I want to do**

I want to redirect to index page when signup process is succeeded.

**What is the problem**

After I filled up username and password, page does not redirect to index page but just stay at signup.html.

**What I have done**

 I suspect that createUser function returns nil and it cause something wrong but I cannot solve it.

**Code**

```
// User model declaration
type User struct {
    gorm.Model
    Username string `form:"username" binding:"required" gorm:"unique;not null"`
    Password string `form:"password" binding:"required"`
}
```

```
// User sign up
func createUser(username string, password string) []error {
    passwordEncrypt, _ := crypto.PasswordEncrypt(password)
    db := gormConnect()
    defer db.Close()
    // Insert
    if err := db.Create(&User{Username: username, Password: passwordEncrypt}).GetErrors(); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return nil
}
```

```
func main(){
router := gin.Default()
    router.LoadHTMLGlob("front/*.html")

    dbInit()

    // index
    router.GET("/", func(c *gin.Context) {
        b_models := dbGetAll()
        num := dbGetNum()
        sumQuantity := dbGetSumQuantity()
        sumPrice := dbGetSumPrice()
        c.HTML(200, "belongings.html", gin.H{"b_models": b_models, "num": num, "sumQuantity": sumQuantity.Totalquantity, "sumPrice": sumPrice.Totalprice})
    })

    // User sign up page
    router.GET("/signup", func(c *gin.Context) {
        c.HTML(200, "signup.html", gin.H{})
    })

    // User sign up process
    router.POST("/signup", func(c *gin.Context) {
        var form User
        // Validation
        if err := c.Bind(&form); err != nil {
            c.HTML(http.StatusBadRequest, "signup.html", gin.H{"err": err})
            log.Println("fail to login because your info is invalid")
            c.Abort()
        } else {
            username := c.PostForm("username")
            password := c.PostForm("password")
            // Process to reject duplicate registered users
            if err := createUser(username, password); err != nil {
                c.HTML(http.StatusBadRequest, "signup.html", gin.H{"err": err})
                c.Abort()
            } else {
                log.Println("success to signup!")
                c.Redirect(302, "/")
            }
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Hi, did you bind index page to any route?

Comment: your redirect ajax request to `/`.

Comment: Hi @meshkati
Yes I did. I wrote this code below.
`// index
 router.GET("/", func(c *gin.Context) {
  b_models := dbGetAll()
  num := dbGetNum()
  sumQuantity := dbGetSumQuantity()
  sumPrice := dbGetSumPrice()
  c.HTML(200, "belongings.html", gin.H{"b_models": b_models, "num": num, "sumQuantity": sumQuantity.Totalquantity, "sumPrice": sumPrice.Totalprice})
 })`

Comment: You can open chrome developer tools https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/open, then switch to the`network` tab to check if the response is correct(the http response code is 302, and `Location` header is `/`)

Comment: @shogo_nakano how does your client (browser) make the request to `POST /signup`? Is it doing a plain form submit? Or is it using some javascript? I'm asking because XMLHttpRequest, for example, does not follow redirects automatically, the redirect response needs to be handled manually in such a case.

Comment: I don't use javascript. I only use golang and HTML in this project.

Comment: https://speakerdeck.com/campoy/understanding-nil?slide=56
I might be stuck in this problem.

Comment: @shogo_nakano if you see the output of `log.Println("success to signup!")` in the stdout of your server then `err` is `nil` and you have a problem with the redirect. If you don't see the log in stdout then `err` is *not* `nil` and you don't have a problem with redirect. Note that, in general, you should check the `DB.Error` field instead of `GetErrors`, note also that an *empty* slice of errors is not the same as a `nil` slice, i.e. `[]error{}` and `[]error(nil)` both represent "no error" but only the latter is `nil`.

Comment: ... so, if you want to keep using `GetErrors()`, you should use `err := createUser(username, password); len(err) > 0 { ...`

Comment: @mkopriva Thank you so much. I can solve this problem and learn much about nil in golang.

Answer (score 0):

you can change page in javascript, i do not understand why would you want your backend to do frontend stuff.

```js
window.location.href = "the_page.html"
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I did in backend because I wanted to make registration process and it has business logic.

Comment: i still suggest you to change page in frontend based of responce from backend

Comment: Is it because response speed and memory efficiency?